# calling constructor of PagedResultList Grails

Tags: grails, constructor, pagedlist

I am trying to call the constructor for PagedResultList:

```
def result = new PagedResultList(list: q, totalCount:q.size())
```

where q is my ArrayList but i get an error saying unable to resolve class. I thought the PagedResultList class was in the grails library, so why am I getting this error. I'm running grails 1.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an import - there are no extra automatically-imported packages or classes in Grails other than what Groovy supports:

```
import grails.orm.PagedResultList
```

Also your map constructor won't work since the class has a real paramaterized constructor; you'll need to do this:

```
def result = new PagedResultList(q, q.size())
```